# Getting the version number for a specific target

Tags: ios, fastlane

I have an iOS project with four targets, but I cannot seem to be able to get the version number for a specific target.

With the following test:

```
  lane :beta do
    puts get_version_number(scheme: 'myApp', target: 'myApp')
  end
```

I get this output:

```
[10:04:05]: --------------------------------
[10:04:05]: --- Step: get_version_number ---
[10:04:05]: --------------------------------
[10:04:05]: Using deprecated option: '--scheme' (true)
[10:04:05]: $ cd /Users/diego/myApp/ios && agvtool what-marketing-version -terse
[10:04:05]: ▸ "myApp.xcodeproj/../myApp-tvOS/Info.plist"=1.0
[10:04:05]: ▸ "myApp.xcodeproj/../myApp-tvOSTests/Info.plist"=1.0
[10:04:05]: ▸ "myApp.xcodeproj/../myApp/Info.plist"=0.9
[10:04:05]: ▸ "myApp.xcodeproj/../myApp Tests/Info.plist"=1.0
[10:04:05]: 1.0
```

The version number returned is 1.0, where as I was expecting 0.9 -- since I specified the `scheme` and `target` for this target: `"myApp.xcodeproj/../myApp/Info.plist"=0.9`

**Edit**

I've installed this [plugin](https://github.com/SiarheiFedartsou/fastlane-plugin-versioning) and it provides finer-grained control over build and version numbers.

Comment: You're getting that because the search breaks somewhere - I'm getting the same thing (maybe you're using React Native like me). Looking at the code for `get_version_number`, another solution is using the deprecated `scheme` field to more or less do a hardcoded search. In your case, `get_version_number(scheme: "myApp/Info")` would work.

Answer (score -2):

Following are the ways to get the version number:

**Objective C:**

```
NSString * appVersionString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
```

**Swift < 3:**

```
let appVersionString: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey("CFBundleShortVersionString") as! String
```

**Swift 3:**

```
let appVersionString: String = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleShortVersionString") as! String
```

Let me know if you need something else.

Comment: Thanks, @tendstoZero, but I was enquiring as to why it wasn't working using Fastlane (note I added the [fastlane] tag to the question.